# How do I clear a Print-queue in Ubuntu?

Tags: printing

I am an absolute beginner with Ubuntu and I appear to have a long queue of documents in my H.P. 840C printer.

Answer (score 131):

The question was how to kill all jobs.
The **simple** way to kill all jobs:

```
lprm -
```

The complicated linux old-school way is below:

Command line:

```
lpstat -o
```

to view outstanding print jobs.

```
cancel -a {printer}
```

to cancel ALL jobs or ...

```
cancel {printerjobid}
```

to cancel 1 job.

---

[man page cancel](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cancel/)

Comment: MAGIC : )
Guys who aren't having success, step 2 above? The readout from lpstat -o should look something like <yourusername_printername>. Just type that verbatim into {printer} in step 2. Worked fine in Ubuntu 15.04. Tnx Rinzwind :)

Comment: Funny, this works very well, but not when using gnome-printers gui. Too bad!

Comment: @Gerstrong do you get a notice? Cuz this is totally outside of gnome-printers scope. Commandline always wins here ;)

Comment: No, notice at all, no reaction. The jobs stays there. Command Line in contrast removes it.

Comment: Likely you need sudo from the gui.

Answer (score 25):

Either

1. Use the printer dialog: type "Printers" in the dash and navigate to the printer
2. Use the CUPS web interface: point your browser at `http://localhost:631/jobs/` and proceed from there
3. Use the command line interface: use `lpq` to see jobs, `lprm` to remove. Refer to `man lprm` for more information.

Comment: Is there something like `lprm *` that will cancel all jobs? Or do we have to go piecemeal?

Comment: @MichaelChirico `man lprm | grep "cancel all jobs"`

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
lpstat -W completed -o
```

to view list of completed jobs.
Use

```
lpstat -o
```

to view list of not-completed jobs.

And to delete job list,just use this command:

```
cancel -a -x
```

This will cancel all pending jobs, as well as deleting them.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, answers given here didn't work for me so here's what I did -

```
ps aux | grep printer
kill {printer job}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `lpstat` and `lprm` but was unable to figure out basic things like the job number and stuff. Instead, I used the command:

```
lpq
```

This produced:

```
zac@computer:~$ lpq
lpq: Error - no default destination available.
```

A quick Internet search and then I tried:

```
zac@computer:~$ lpq -a
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                     Total Size
1st     zac     85      TorahNT.odt                 59392 bytes
```

FINALLY I find the all important Job number: 85!

NOW I run `lprm`:

```
zac@computer:~$ lprm 85
zac@computer:~$
```

And to confirm I did this:

```
zac@computer:~$ lpq -a
no entries
zac@computer:~$
```

Finally, the printer queue is empty.

Comment: Really nice clear answer - very helpful for people unfamiliar with the commands, thanks!